# Мобильное меню не убирается

Tags: jquery, меню

Ребята, помогите, в js совсем чуть чуть разбираюсь, а в jquery совсем нет, есть минимизированный скрипт мобильного меню, после нажатие на пункт оно переходит на нужный раздел на лендинге, все работает, НО ОНО НЕ УБИРАЕТСЯ. Как я понял, нужно убрать класс vs-body-visible у vs-menu-wrapper при клике на a или li без класса, которые там судя по всему динамически появляются.

Я на js мог бы убрать просто класc при клике, а на jquery не могу, что куда добавить?

```
!
function (e) {
        e.fn.vsmobilemenu = function (n) {
                var s = e.extend({
                        menuContainer: ".vs-mobile-menu",
                        menuToggleClass: "vs-menu-visible",
                        expandScreenWidth: 992,
                        containerClass: "vs-menu-container",
                        meanExpandClass: "vs-mean-expand",
                        subMenuParent: "vs-item-has-children",
                        subMenuParentToggle: "vs-active",
                        subMenuClass: "vs-submenu",
                        subMenuToggleClass: "vs-open",
                        toggleSpeed: 400,
                        menuBody: ".vs-menu-wrapper",
                        bodyToggleClass: "vs-body-visible",
                        menuToggleBtn: ".vs-menu-toggle",
                        btnToggleClass: "vs-active"
                }, n);
                return this.each((function () {
                        function n(n) {
                                var l = e(n).next("ul").find("ul");
                                l.hasClass(s.subMenuToggleClass) && (l.removeClass(s.subMenuToggleClass), l.slideUp(s.toggleSpeed), l.parent().removeClass(s.subMenuParentToggle))
                        }
                        function l(l) {
                                e(l).next("ul").length > 0 ? (e(l).parent().toggleClass(s.subMenuParentToggle), e(l).next("ul").slideToggle(s.toggleSpeed), e(l).next("ul").toggleClass(s.subMenuToggleClass), n(l)) : e(l).prev("ul").length > 0 && (e(l).parent().toggleClass(s.subMenuParentToggle), e(l).prev("ul").slideToggle(s.toggleSpeed), e(l).prev("ul").toggleClass(s.subMenuToggleClass), n(l))
                        }
                        function a() {
                                g < s.expandScreenWidth ? (u.css("display", "none"), e(s.menuContainer).css("display", ""), e(s.menuBody).css("display", "")) : (u.css("display", ""), e(s.menuContainer).css("display", "none"), e(s.menuBody).css("display", "none"))
                        }
                        var o = e(this).html();
                        e(s.menuContainer).each((function () {
                                e(this).on("click", (function (e) {
                                        e.stopPropagation()
                                })),
                                e(this).html(o),
                                e(this).find("li").each((function () {
                                        var n = e(this).find("ul");
                                        n.addClass(s.subMenuClass),
                                        n.css("display", "none"),
                                        n.parent().addClass(s.subMenuParent),
                                        n.prev("a").addClass(s.meanExpandClass),
                                        n.next("a").addClass(s.meanExpandClass)
                                }))
                        }));
                        var t = "." + s.meanExpandClass;
                        e(t).each((function () {
                                e(this).on("click", (function (e) {
                                        e.preventDefault(),
                                        l(this)
                                }))
                        })),
                        e(s.menuToggleBtn).each((function () {
                                e(this).on("click", (function (n) {
                                        n.preventDefault(),
                                        e(s.menuToggleBtn).toggleClass(s.btnToggleClass),
                                        e(s.menuBody).length > 0 && e(s.menuBody).toggleClass(s.bodyToggleClass),
                                        e(s.menuContainer).length > 0 && e(s.menuContainer).toggleClass(s.menuToggleClass),


                                        function () {
                                                var n = "." + s.subMenuClass;
                                                e(n).each((function () {
                                                        e(this).hasClass(s.subMenuToggleClass) && (e(this).removeClass(s.subMenuToggleClass), e(this).css("display", "none"), e(this).parent().removeClass(s.subMenuParentToggle))
                                                }))
                                        }()
                                }))
                        })),
                        e(s.menuBody).length > 0 && e(s.menuBody).on("click", (function (n) {
                                n.stopPropagation(),
                                e(s.menuBody).hasClass(s.bodyToggleClass) && (e(s.menuBody).removeClass(s.bodyToggleClass), e(s.menuContainer).removeClass(s.menuToggleClass), e(s.menuToggleBtn).removeClass(s.btnToggleClass))
                        })),
                        e(s.menuBody).find("div").on("click", (function (e) {
                                e.stopPropagation()
                        }));
                        var u = e(this);
                        let g = e(window).width();
                        a(),
                        e(window).on("resize", (function () {
                                g = e(window).width(),
                                a()
                        }))
                }))
        }
}(jQuery);
```

```
<div class="vs-menu-wrapper">
                        <div class="vs-menu-area">
                                <button class="vs-menu-toggle text-theme">
                                        <i class="fal fa-times">
                                        </i>
                                </button>
                                <div class="mobile-logo">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="assets\img\logo-krasnodar.png" alt="Clianio"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="vs-mobile-menu link-inherit">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
```